# Regex causes browser to crash?

Tags: jquery, regex

I know this has been asked countless times, and I have checked almost all the answers on Stackoverflow but I can't get this one to work correctly.

When a user enters a URL to an image on my site, I want to check if the URL is valid before appending the image to the DOM.

Here is what I'm using currently:

```
function isValidURL(textval) {
  var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|co\.uk|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
  return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```

This has been working fine for sometime until I tried to enter the following URL into the textfield and it just keeps crashing the whole browser!

```
http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/02/11/2595F03200000578-2949888-image-a-64_1423695120362.jpg
```

I know that URL works fine and I created a JSFiddle to test it here **http://jsfiddle.net/Lg0an1hz/**

Now try entering the URL into this updated version of the same fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/Lg0an1hz/1/**

My whole browser crashes!

Can anyone please provide me with the correct regex to make sure a URL is entered. In fact, I just really need to check that whatever the user entered begins with a `http://`, `https://`, or a `www`. I don't think theres any other start to a URL unless someone knows better.

Comment: It seems as though that expression is not the most efficient and can cause [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: I have no idea what regex I should use. I just copied that one from an another answer on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out <[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg0an1hz/3/)> :

```
function isValidURL(textval) {
 var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

  return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it work on `keyup` rather than on `click`?

Comment: Sure, just change `$('#verify').on('click')` to `$('#url').on('keyup')`